# How do i create argument tuples with assignments?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

In my problem i want to perform a fit, in a loop. The length of the tuple for the fit argument changes according to the amount of data sets. This i can do by standard tuple methods, the problem are the assignments of the constraints for example.

Equations or assignments are forbidden in this form of declaration. I played around with args and kwargs but i could not figure out the right syntax.

```
#A short example shows what i am triing to do:
#This one works of course
N = 10
sigma = 10.0
yn = np.random.normal(size=N, scale=sigma)

#This is forbidden:
N = 10
sigma = 10.0
rndArgs = (size=N, scale=sigma)
yn = np.random.normal(*rndArgs)
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Even if you were to unpack the tuple, its contents depend on `N` and `sigma` values, so why are you asking about the tuple itself? Each member of the tuple is already variable

Answer (score 0):

To pass named arguments, you need a dictionary:

```
rndArgs = dict(size=N, scale=sigma)
yn = np.random.normal(**rndArgs)
```

Comment: Thank you i did not try this :)